# Finding the coordinate of a point

Tags: geometry

[image]

Assuma we know $xa, ya, xb, yb, sc, yc$. How can we find $(xd,yd)$ in Mathematica?

Comment: Can you explain in words how the points a, b, c and d relate to each other?  Possibly `RegionNearest` with `InfiniteLine`, if you're simply dropping a perpendicular to ab from c.

Comment: This is just another take on a projection of `{xc,yc}` onto `Line[{{xa,ya},{xb,yb}}]`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
In[226]:= RegionNearest[InfiniteLine[{{ax, ay}, {bx, by}}], {cx, cy}]

Out[226]= {ax + ((-ax + bx) ((-ax + bx) (-ax + cx) + (-ay + by) (-ay + cy)))/((-ax + bx)^2 + (-ay + by)^2), 
 ay + ((-ay + by) ((-ax + bx) (-ax + cx) + (-ay + by) (-ay + cy)))/((-ax + bx)^2 + (-ay + by)^2)}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {1, 0};
b = {5, 1};
c = {2, 3};
```

Then d would be the projection of the vector from a to c onto that from a to b:

```
d = Projection[c - a, b - a]
```

offset by the position of point a:

```
ListPlot[{a, b, c, d + a}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 6}, {-5, 6}}]
```